# Google Email Settings API Change?

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-email-settings-api

Does anyone know if the Admin SDK / Email Settings API has changed recently?  Previously we were able to delegate a user account for a user that was disabled, this is no longer that case.

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any error? what is the process you are doing to impersonate the disabled user?

Comment: @Gerardo could you please take a look at the issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33293812/unable-to-delegate-users-using-email-settings-api)?

Comment: @user3497630 hey, I am facing the same issue. Did you find anything?