# Unable to delegate users using Email Settings API

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-email-settings-api

Does anyone know if the Admin SDK / Email Settings API has changed recently? Previously we were able to delegate a user account for a user that was disabled, this is no longer that case.

Following is the stacktrace:

```
400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}. Stacktrace follows:
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:269)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory$OAuth2Token.refreshToken(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:258)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.handleSessionExpiredException(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:702)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.handleSessionExpiredException(GoogleService.java:738)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.insert(GoogleService.java:617)
    at com.google.gdata.client.appsforyourdomain.AppsForYourDomainService.insert(AppsForYourDomainService.java:100)
    at sample.appsforyourdomain.gmailsettings.OpenDevGmailSettingsService.insertSettings(OpenDevGmailSettingsService.java:182)
    at sample.appsforyourdomain.gmailsettings.OpenDevGmailSettingsService.addEmailDelegate(OpenDevGmailSettingsService.java:1073)
    at com.opendev.core.GoogleEmailDelegateService.addEmailDelegate(GoogleEmailDelegateService.groovy:76)
    at com.opendev.core.EmailDelegateController$_save_closure2_closure3.doCall(EmailDelegateController.groovy:68)
    at com.opendev.core.EmailDelegateController$_save_closure2.doCall(EmailDelegateController.groovy:63)
    at com.opendev.core.EmailDelegateController.save(EmailDelegateController.groovy:62)
    at grails.plugin.multitenant.core.servlet.CurrentTenantServletFilter.doFilter(CurrentTenantServletFilter.java:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

I update GmailSettingsService and created OpenDevGmailSettingsService with a new constructor:

```
public OpenDevGmailSettingsService(String domain, String serviceAccountId, String serviceAccountUser, String serviceAccountApplicationName, String privateKeyFileLocation) throws AuthenticationException {
        super(serviceAccountApplicationName, Constants.PROTOCOL, Constants.APPS_APIS_DOMAIN);
        this.domain = domain;

    new GenericFeed().declareExtensions(getExtensionProfile());

    try {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        List<String> SCOPES = Arrays
                .asList("https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/");
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountId)
                .setServiceAccountUser(serviceAccountUser)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
                        new File(privateKeyFileLocation)).build();
        this.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuthenticationException(
                "Unable to initialize Gmail Settings service" + e);
    }
}
```

Here `serviceAccountUser` is the admin-user-email-id of current user's domain.

Comment: Open a case with Google support team

Comment: @AMS, I did. But, they say there is no change at their service end. Not sure why it abruptly stopped working.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946453/google-api-oauth2-service-account-error-invalid-grant

Comment: Did you get any answer?